# Vectorized KL divergence calculation between all pairs of rows of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, scipy.stats

I would like to find out the KL divergence between all pairs of rows of a matrix. To explain, let's assume there is a matrix `V` of shape `N x K`. Now I want to create a matrix `L` of dimension `N x N`, where each element `L[i,j] = KL(V[i,:],V[j,:])`. So far I have used the following [`scipy.stats.entropy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) to compute

```py
upper_triangle = [entropy(V[i,:],V[j,:]) for (i,j) in itertools.combinations(range(N,2)]
lower_triangle = [entropy(V[j,:],V[i,:]) for (i,j) in itertools.combinations(range(N,2)]

L = np.zeroes((N,N))

L[np.triu_indices(N,k = 1)] = upper_triangle
L[np.tril_indices(N,k = -1)] = lower_triangle
```

Is there a cleverer way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after massaging the equation for KL divergence a bit the following equation should work too and of course, it's magnitudes faster,

```
kl = np.dot(V, np.log(Vc).T)
right = kl + kl.T
left = np.tile(np.diag(kl),(kl.shape[0],1))
left = left + left.T
L = left - right
```

Comment: Sorry, what is `Vc`?